# Does C# remove the characters &#10; &#x2022; from a string?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this C# code used to populate a label on the screen of a phone. Note that it's not HTML source being used here.

```
c1Label.Text = "To select cards for your deck you can one of a number of options &#10; &#x2022;
```

and this XAML

```
<local:JustifiedLabel x:Name="c1Label" Text= "To select cards for your deck you can one of a number of options &#10; &#x2022;
```

The former shows &#10 as part of the text but the XAML version works fine and shows this as a line feed followed by a bullet.

Comment: [Probably worth a read](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is to be expected. Both languages (C# and XML) have different rules, especially regarding what characters are “special” and how they have to be escaped when you want to use them anyway. In the C# string

```
"&#10; &#x2022;"
```

are just exactly those letters since they have no special meaning to the C# compiler. In XML they are numeric character references, and are an escape mechanism of including arbitrary characters.

Conversely, in C# the following

```
"\n \u2022"
```

represents a line feed and a bullet. But in XML it's just the exact characters as written.

You can construct endless such examples with almost any two different languages. Yes, this means you cannot just copy text from one language and expect it to represent the same string in another language. If you're transforming one language into another it's easy to handle programmatically, when you're copying stuff around manually you just have to live with this and adapt accordingly.